Pandas not reading first Excel line
I am currently experiencing an issue using panda's read_excel function.
# create a dataframe containing all data points
df = pd.read_excel(data_path)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
print(df.iloc[0])
df = df.iloc[1:]

In this code, I read the excel file and set the name of each column based on the first line in my excel file, which does have the column names. However, df.iloc[0] in the above code instead reads in the second line of data in my excel file, which holds numerical data values instead of column names.
To diagnose this issue, I put a blank row above all of the data in my excel file, and the program ended up reading in the column names correctly and running as expected, producing the correct graphs based on the data. However, I want the code to run without this additional blank space at the top of the excel file.

It might be a good idea to provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. some data we can save as an Excel file and then read using your code to see that the issue also happens to us.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Resolved. Needed to add header=None argument to my read_excel call.

According to the docs, we should use None when there's no header, so it might be that headers in excel files are not what you mean. I don't remember anymore, but maybe your header is just a normal row, and that's why None does what you want? What does df.columns.tolist() show? I'd assume not the name of the columns in your header.

You are correct that my headers are just a normal row at the top of my excel file, which is why None does what I want. I am now aware excel has actual headers and footers. df.columns.tolist() now prints the correct columns after my fix, but did not originally.
